# rand function in mysql query take too many time to execute

Tags: mysql, database

> Query_time: 1.021086  Lock_time: 0.000081 Rows_sent: 5  Rows_examined: 23020
> SET timestamp=1391577349;
>
> SELECT t.* FROM `table` WHERE publish_on <= '2014-02-05' ORDER BY
> rand() LIMIT 5;

I take more time to execution. How to make it faster,

How to Use rand function functionality without using rand

Comment: Try this, for starters: https://www.google.ru/search?q=mysql+efficient+random+row&oq=mysql+efficient+ra&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.10532j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I believe sorting by `rand()` requires a full table scan (in pretty much any database), since it is a volatile function. That's why it's slow.

Comment: Have you looked at answers to similar questions?